# Varying modal content based on trigger button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I am using http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target, however, when I use the code in my own project the function does not work. I am very new to this so it is probably something simple.

Here is my code: http://hastebin.com/comikucidi.xml

Thank you.

Edit:
Just created a brand new document and copied the bootstrap page. The function still is not working

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Bootstrap - Prebuilt Layout</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Open modal for @mdo</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@fat">Open modal for @fat</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@getbootstrap">Open modal for @getbootstrap</button>
...more buttons...

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Recipient:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Message:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
  // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
  // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient)
  modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
})
</script>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed --> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add your code in the post too, people like that in here and you will have more chances to get help.

Comment: I did try but the format for some reason messes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to attach the handler to a non existing id, try to use the id of your modal :

```
$('#delete').on('show.bs.modal',
```

instead of `#exampleModal`.

EDIT:

You should also add

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //your code here
});
```

around your code, to attach your handler after the element is properly created.

Comment: Ah yes, however it still did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Put the script at the end of jQuery library calls likes this:

jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) 
[here]

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {...}
```

If you do this, it works!